# dnx ef is not recognized although defined in project.json

Tags: entity-framework-core

While starting my asp.net 5.0 application + EF 7 RC1. I get the message to apply model change so I click the apply button but then I get an error with the message I should run "dnx ef database update" from the command line. So I did on the CMD within my project with my migration folder and the context class.

But I get this error:

```
Error: Unable to load application or execute command 'EntityFramework.Commands'. Available commands: web, ef.
```

In the project.json there I have put the:

```
 "commands": {
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Please state a reason for downvote!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a reference to `EntityFramework.Commands` in that project. Add a reference to it in project.json.